# Kubeflow deployment Azure infinite loop logout

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, logout, kubeflow

I deployed Kubeflow on Azure AKS. When I click the logout button it seems a new login is triggered and then I get redirected to the central dashboard. I think the logout in Azure active directory is not triggered. If I logout via

```
login.microsoftonline.com/<Application ID>/oauth2/v2.0/logout
```

I get logout from AAD. When I then click the logout button the session is terminated and I am logged out.

I tried to solve this with a virtualService, but cannot get it to work. Is someone having the same issues or knows a solution?

Comment: Use in private/incognito browser and check

Comment: Which tools are you using to check?